# What dependencies to add to make hhtpclient sample work

Tags: java, xml, apache, maven, post

I am working on a software project my company, and i need to test an http connection and send an example xml to server and get the response. Client sends us an example connection method and i try to test it. Below there is the sample connection method.

```
   public String postApplicationRequest(String content) throws Exception {
    final HttpPost post = new HttpPost("url");
    final HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(content, ContentType.create("text/xml", "UTF-8"));
    post.setEntity(entity);
    final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    AuthScope authScopre = new AuthScope("www.myhost.com", 80, AuthScope.ANY_REALM);
    Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password");
    HttpState httpState = client.getState();
    httpState.setCredentials(authScopre, credentials);
    final HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
        System.out.println("call was not successful");
        return null;
    }
    return IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent());
}
```

I added dependency to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
<artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
<version>4.3.6</version>
```

But HttpEntity is not found to import. Actually I am confused of which version of httpClient i need to add pom.xml. Also is there any other dependencies do i need to make this code sample run.

Any suggestion would be very helpful. Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
  <version>4.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried but it says "Missing artifact org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.2:compile", probably our maven version is old dated. Unfortunately i can't do anything with it.

Comment: i tried 4.3.2 version it compiles but i dont have any import suggestion for HttpPost object

Comment: It should be in org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost